# How to use browser cookies programmatically

Tags: java, python, cookies, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I have a crawler that automates the login and crawling for a website, but since the login was changed it is not working anymore.

I am wondering, can I feed the browser cookie (aka, I manually log-in) to my HTTP request? Is there anything particularly wrong in principle that wouldn't make this work? How do I find the browser cookies relevant for the website?

If it works, how do I get the "raw" cookie strings I can stick into my HTTP request?

I am quite new to this area, so forgive my ignorant questions. I can use either PYthon or Java

Comment: Cookies are just strings passed around in request and response headers. Both browsers and Python and Java code can do this without any real difficulty.

Comment: Using a library like [`requests'](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) makes maintaining cookies trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the login information (and usually in response to many other requests) the server will set some cookies to the client, you must keep track of them and send them back to the server for each subsequent request.

A full implementation would also keep track of the time they are supposed to be stored.

Comment: Thanks LtWorf. If it works, how do I get the "raw" cookie strings I can stick into my HTTP request?

Comment: In the response you will find an header like this: Set-Cookie: DWf1a57e669467908068a7e4f21304a6f1=deleted; expires=Wed, 30-Nov-2011 15:23:06 GMT; path=/somthing/; httponly

cookies are key-value, plus they have other options.

Comment: By the way since you said it works, you might want to consider accepting my answer...